# Java Memory Model Actions

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-model, java-memory-model

I'm trying to understand the [Java Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4), but I'm having a bit of trouble regarding *actions*. I understand the definition of an action as <*t, k, v, u*>, but I don't quite understand how a program is broken into actions, and how abstract these actions are.

My first assumption was that actions are atomic. `var1 = var2` would be broken into two actions - a read of `var2` and a write to `var1`, but an example [here](http://rsim.cs.illinois.edu/Pubs/popl05.pdf) suggests that `var1 = var2` is an action itself. So each action corresponds to a statement in the source code.

How does this work with an if statement? For example, if we had `if(r1 == r2 && r3 == r4) { ... }`, would the entire statement be one action, or broken into multiple actions (and if so, how do the corresponding actions stay 'connected' as an if statement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are defined in [JLS 17.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2), which particularly focuses on "inter-thread actions:"

> An *inter-thread action* is an action performed by one thread that can be detected or directly influenced by another thread. ... This specification is only concerned with inter-thread actions.

The full list of those actions is at the link (and not really worth copying in full here), but it includes reads and writes of variables.

The question of `var1 = var2` depends on what `var1` and `var2` are. If they're both fields on a class, then those are two separate actions (the read of `var2` and write to `var`). If either of them is a local variable, then its state belongs to the method's stack frame, which is inherently thread-local and thus not an inter-thread action.

For instance, if `var2` is a field and `var1` is a local variable, then the only inter-thread action is the read of `var2` — the write of that value to the local variable is *not* an inter-thread action, since it can only be observed by the thread that the local stack frame belongs to.

Similarly, `if (r1 == r2 && r3 == r4)` can be up to 4 actions: the reads of the four variables, if they are fields. The results of the `==` and `&&` operations are thread-local, and thus don't count as inter-thread actions.

Comment: So say we had a statement `r1 = x`, where `x` is a shared variable `x`, and `r1` is local to some thread. According to the second paper I linked, this would be committed as an action `r1 = x`. However, only the read of `x` can be detected or directly influenced by another thread, so why is `r1` still considered?

Comment: What do you mean by "`r1`  is still considered"?  The action is the read of `x`. A read requires reading data _from_ somewhere _to_ somewhere else; the `r1` is just the "somewhere else" in this case, and is likely just a register.

Comment: Thanks yshavit, I think I'm following. So if `r1` in that example was also a shared variable, `r1 = x` would be two independent actions - `read x` and `write r1 = value of x`, correct?